# How to call viewDidLoad from applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, viewdidload

there are a few other answers for this question, but they doesn't help me so much..

so i need a solution to run the `viewDidLoad` method from the `AppDelegate` especially from the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. please help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You don't call viewDidLoad yourself, the OS calls it. You create/load your UIViewController object and as a consequence viewDidLoad will get called by the OS. Instead of asking this question, tell us what it is you want to do rather than assuming calling viewDidLoad is the solution (it isn't the solution because as I said you don't call it).

Comment: Ok. In my normal ViewController there is a method which should be called automatically if the app become active. I've tried to call the method as an public method with +(void), but this is not possible for me, because that what the method should do can't run in an public method so i can't call the method from applicationDidBecomeActive, but the viewDidLoad does via [self method]; this was my sense, sorry for that i am really new to ios programming, but maybe you can help me. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it seems you want to call a function on the view controller when the app becomes active?

You can add an observer to your view controller, if the class has an init method that is getting called do it there, if not do it in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appBecameActive)
                                             name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

You need to remove it when the object is removed, so add this:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Then the method appBecameActive will be called every time the app becomes active

```
- (void) appBecameActive
{
    call your method here
}
```

P.S. From your comments + is for class methods. Which with a view controller is probably not what you want. Read about class methods versus object methods to continue your iOS education.

Comment: Tank you very much! This is the solution i was searching for! :) also Thanks for education tipps.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is always called by the system, and you ideally shouldn't call it manually. That said, one way to call it is to access the .view property of a `UIViewController`. This does call `viewDidLoad`, if it hasn't already been called.

If there is some piece of code that should run everytime a view appears, you should write your code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: okay. if it's not possible to call viewDidLoad, do you know how i can call a private method wich is in my ViewController class from the AppDelegate class... if i make the method to an public method with +(void) the function in the method won't run.. Thanks so far!